# Connects To The Device That's The Closest

Tags: bluetooth

I need some expert advice or ideas.

Please note I'm not a student nor practitioner of Electrical Engineering.

I'm working on a product idea where a device will automatically connect to another device (via bluetooth?) if it's the closest device within 30 feet range (bluetooth's distance)

Let's say a Television with bluetooth.

In the living room, there are 20 bluetooth remote controls that can connect to the TV.

Is it possible to connect just one remote control because it's the closest to the TV?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's this FM Capture Effect which you may be interested in. The phenomenon is exploited in wireless microphone systems. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capture_effect

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth does not provide any functionality for proximity measurement. The signal strength is an accessible measure (RSSI) but does not imply nearness: A nearer source behind a wall is likely to have weaker signal than a source in line of sight but much further away.

Depending on the actual purpose, switching between (previously paired) Bluetooth partners based on RSSI is a viable approach.

If proximity is a hard requirement, an ancillary mechanism using time of flight of a broadcast packet from the base unit to all listening units, and selection of whichever target responds first, is an option. Note though that if the responding unit has a delay in responding, this will throw all time of flight assumptions off.